# Table with fixed right column

Tags: php, css, html-table

I want a table having `Fixed Column`. I want right column to be fixed. I found a script to fix left most column. I used that code to fix right most column.

**HTML**

```
<div><table>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 4</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 5</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 6</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 7</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 8</td></tr>
<tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="headcol">Row 9</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 600px;
    overflow-x:scroll;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.headcol {
    position:absolute;
    width:5em;
    left: 820px;
}
.long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }
</style>
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/AbjVy/) is the demo of that script.

The problem is that when I view this page at different resolution or change zoom level of browser, position of the right most column get changed.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a CSS style for the right column with **float: right**; **display:block** should  solve the problem

Comment: In your demo the right column shares the same div and headcol styles with the other columns. Something like a RightCol style, for example, to be applied only to the right column might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-height` and `max-height`